# Bash simple script not working proerly

Tags: shell-script, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use this bash code to get the temperature of my Raspberry Pi, convert to Fahrenheit and display both Fahrenheit and Celsius then save as text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
cpu="$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)"
far=$((cpu/1000))
far2=$((far*9))
far3=$((far2/5))
far4=$((far3+32))
echo "CPU => $((cpu/1000))' C or $((far4))' F"
echo ""
echo "Pi temp $far4 degrees F" > /var/www/html/pitemp.txt
```

However when i run it, the Fahrenheit is ok, but why is the Celsius not shown?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nano checkTemp.sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./checkTemp.sh

./checkTemp.sh: line 3: temp=40.0'C: command not found
CPU => 0' C or 32' F

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
temp=40.0'C
```

I checked the value of cpu and far but it seems not to be working. Any advice?[solved]

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo ""
cpu="$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | sed -E 's/.*=([0-9.]*).*/\1/')"
## convert to Fahrenheit
far=$( echo "$cpu * 9/5 + 32" | bc -l)
## Remove extra decimal digits
printf "CPU => %.2f' C or %.2f' F\n" "$cpu" "$far"
echo ""
printf "Pi temp %.2f degrees F\n" "$cpu" > /var/www/html/pitemp.txt
echo "C:$cpu F:$far"
```

this new code is working however the Fahrenheit seems has issue becasue the output is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nano checkTemp.sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./checkTemp.sh

./checkTemp.sh: line 5: bc: command not found
CPU => 43.00' C or 0.00' F

C:43.0 F:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp
temp=43.0'C
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Also, please show us the output of `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp`.

Comment: I edited it please have a look again. and the temperature is 40~44.0c Now.

Comment: Are you sure that is _exactly_ the script you are running? That should give you an `invalid arithmetic operator` error, not a command not found.

Comment: I am sure and i am following this instrument:https://nebulousthinking.wordpress.com/2019/07/27/displaying-your-raspberry-pis-temperature-on-its-home-web-page/ his code has multiple error so i was fixing

Comment: That code is _so_ wrong, it's not even close to what you need. But the error message you show cannot come from the code you're showing, so you must be doing something else. In any case, does my script work?

Comment: it's ok for display however when come to the file it was not the thing i expect becasue it's show `Pi temp $.2f degrees F` not a actual degree , what i need do to fix this issue? if i can record the actual degree to the file then this question will be perfect solved. and the display  showing `CPU => 44.00' C or 0.00' F`

Comment: Whoops, yes, that was a typo. I fixed it now, sorry!

Comment: hi Could you please tell me why the Fahrenheit is not working? the Celsius is ok thought, i want make a perfect solution@terdon

Comment: It should work. I am testing by setting the value of `$cpu` to `44.0` manually and I get `CPU => 44.00' C or 111.20' F`. If you are getting something else, then you must be doing something different. Please [edit] your question and show us the _exact_ script you are running now. Also,  add `echo "C:$cpu F:$far"` to the end of the script, run it, and show us the output.

Comment: Well, the error message is quite clear, it seems to me: `./checkTemp.sh: line 5: bc: command not found`. Look up how to install `bc` on your distribution

Comment: See updated answer. I added an approach that doesn't need `bc`.

Comment: thanks very much for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$cpu` variable holds `temp=40.0'C`. That isn't a number, you can't divide that or multiply it, you need to first extract the actual numerical value. So you need to get the `40.0` out. You can do this with:

```
cpu="$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | sed -E 's/.*=([0-9.]*).*/\1/')"
```

The next problem is that bash cannot do floating point arithmetic. So it can't deal with non-integer values. You need another tool for that, something like `bc`:

```
far=$(echo "$cpu/1000" | bc -l)
```

Of course, since your CPU temperature will never be higher than (or remotely near) 1000 degrees Celsius, this division cannot be right. The formula for converting Celsius to Fahrenheit seems to be:

```
T(°F) = T(°C) × 9/5 + 32
```

You can do this in one step. Putting all this together, this should be a working version of your script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo ""
cpu="$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | sed -E 's/.*=([0-9.]*).*/\1/')"
## convert to Fahrenheit
far=$( echo "$cpu * 9/5 + 32" | bc -l)
## Remove extra decimal digits
printf "CPU => %.2f °C or %.2f °F\n" "$cpu" "$far"
echo ""
printf "Pi temp %.2f degrees F\n" "$far" > /var/www/html/pitemp.txt
```

If you don't have `bc`, you can use this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo ""
cpu="$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | sed -E 's/.*=([0-9.]*).*/\1/')"
## convert to Fahrenheit
far=$( perl -le 'print $ARGV[0] * 9/5 + 32' "$cpu")
## Remove extra decimal digits
printf "CPU => %.2f °C or %.2f °F\n" "$cpu" "$far"
echo ""
printf "Pi temp %.2f degrees F\n" "$far" > /var/www/html/pitemp.txt
```